# Process Tasks Using Servers

Tags: python, algorithm

A problem from leetcode:
https://leetcode.com/problems/process-tasks-using-servers.
I had a simple solution for it, that's using min heap to store all servers and dictionary to check whether there're free servers at a time. But it cannot pass all testcases (26/36).
Could anyone help to point out my faults?

Problem:

You are given two 0-indexed integer arrays servers and tasks of lengths n​​​​​​ and m​​​​​​ respectively. servers[i] is the weight of the i​​​​​​th​​​​ server, and tasks[j] is the time needed to process the j​​​​​​th​​​​ task in seconds.

Tasks are assigned to the servers using a task queue. Initially, all servers are free, and the queue is empty.

At second j, the jth task is inserted into the queue (starting with the 0th task being inserted at second 0). As long as there are free servers and the queue is not empty, the task in the front of the queue will be assigned to a free server with the smallest weight, and in case of a tie, it is assigned to a free server with the smallest index.

If there are no free servers and the queue is not empty, we wait until a server becomes free and immediately assign the next task. If multiple servers become free at the same time, then multiple tasks from the queue will be assigned in order of insertion following the weight and index priorities above.

A server that is assigned task j at second t will be free again at second t + tasks[j].

Build an array ans​​​​ of length m, where ans[j] is the index of the server the j​​​​​​th task will be assigned to.

Return the array ans​​​​.

Example 1:

Input: servers = [3,3,2], tasks = [1,2,3,2,1,2]
Output: [2,2,0,2,1,2]
Explanation: Events in chronological order go as follows:

- At second 0, task 0 is added and processed using server 2 until second 1.
- At second 1, server 2 becomes free. Task 1 is added and processed using server 2 until second 3.
- At second 2, task 2 is added and processed using server 0 until second 5.
- At second 3, server 2 becomes free. Task 3 is added and processed using server 2 until second 5.
- At second 4, task 4 is added and processed using server 1 until second 5.
- At second 5, all servers become free. Task 5 is added and processed using server 2 until second 7.

```
from heapq import *

class Solution:
    def assignTasks(self, servers: List[int], tasks: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        
        h = []
        N = len(servers)
        M = len(tasks)
        freeDic = {}
        res = []
        for i in range(N):
            heappush(h, (servers[i], i))
        time = 0
        j = 0
        while j < M:
            if time in freeDic:
                for freeServer in freeDic[time]:
                    heappush(h, freeServer)
                del freeDic[time]
            if len(h) > 0:
                s = heappop(h)
                res.append(s[1])
                timeToFree = time + tasks[j]
                if timeToFree in freeDic:
                    freeDic[timeToFree].append(s)
                else:
                    freeDic[timeToFree] = [s]
                j += 1
            time += 1
            
                
        return res
```

Failed case:

```
Input:
[338,890,301,532,284,930,426,616,919,267,571,140,716,859,980,469,628,490,195,664,925,652,503,301,917,563,82,947,910,451,366,190,253,516,503,721,889,964,506,914,986,718,520,328,341,765,922,139,911,578,86,435,824,321,942,215,147,985,619,865]
[773,537,46,317,233,34,712,625,336,221,145,227,194,693,981,861,317,308,400,2,391,12,626,265,710,792,620,416,267,611,875,361,494,128,133,157,638,632,2,158,428,284,847,431,94,782,888,44,117,489,222,932,494,948,405,44,185,587,738,164,356,783,276,547,605,609,930,847,39,579,768,59,976,790,612,196,865,149,975,28,653,417,539,131,220,325,252,160,761,226,629,317,185,42,713,142,130,695,944,40,700,122,992,33,30,136,773,124,203,384,910,214,536,767,859,478,96,172,398,146,713,80,235,176,876,983,363,646,166,928,232,699,504,612,918,406,42,931,647,795,139,933,746,51,63,359,303,752,799,836,50,854,161,87,346,507,468,651,32,717,279,139,851,178,934,233,876,797,701,505,878,731,468,884,87,921,782,788,803,994,67,905,309,2,85,200,368,672,995,128,734,157,157,814,327,31,556,394,47,53,755,721,159,843]

Output:
[26,50,47,11,56,31,18,55,32,9,4,2,23,53,43,0,44,30,6,51,29,51,15,17,22,34,38,33,42,3,25,10,49,51,7,58,16,21,19,31,19,12,41,35,45,52,13,59,47,36,1,28,48,39,24,8,46,20,5,54,27,37,14,57,40,59,8,45,4,51,47,7,58,4,31,23,54,7,9,56,2,46,56,1,17,42,11,30,12,44,14,32,7,10,23,1,29,27,6,10,33,24,19,10,35,30,35,10,17,49,50,36,29,1,48,44,7,11,24,57,42,30,10,55,3,20,38,15,7,46,32,21,40,16,59,30,53,17,18,22,51,11,53,36,57,26,5,56,36,55,31,34,57,7,52,37,31,10,0,51,41,2,32,25,0,7,49,47,13,14,24,57,28,4,45,43,39,38,8,2,44,45,29,25,25,12,54,5,44,30,27,23,26,7,33,58,41,25,52,40,58,9,52,40]

Expected:
[26,50,47,11,56,31,18,55,32,9,4,2,23,53,43,0,44,30,6,51,29,51,15,17,22,34,38,33,42,3,25,10,49,51,7,58,16,21,19,31,19,12,41,35,45,52,13,59,47,36,1,28,48,39,24,8,46,20,5,54,27,37,14,57,40,59,8,45,4,51,47,7,58,4,31,23,54,7,9,56,2,46,56,1,17,42,11,30,12,44,14,32,7,10,23,1,29,27,6,10,33,24,19,10,35,30,35,10,17,49,50,36,29,1,48,44,7,11,24,57,42,30,10,55,3,20,38,15,7,46,32,21,40,16,59,30,53,17,18,22,51,11,53,36,57,26,5,36,56,55,31,34,57,7,52,37,31,10,0,51,41,2,32,25,0,7,49,47,13,14,24,57,28,4,45,43,39,38,8,2,44,45,29,25,25,12,54,5,44,30,27,23,26,7,33,58,41,25,52,40,58,9,52,40]
```

Answer (score 1):

I experimented with this question but did not post anything because I assumed
it was off-topic; however, I guess that was mistaken. Since you're solving
puzzles on LeetCode, I assume you want the satisfaction of writing your own
implementation, so I'll refrain from posting my own approach to the problem. I
believe your current code has two problems, both related to the **management of
time**.

**Problem 1: you never start more than one task on any particular second.**
That's that right approach if there is always a free server. However, if
servers are all busy when a task is supposed to start, on the next second,
we now have two tasks eligible for starting. And if there are two free
servers, we should start both tasks immediately. A short example:

```text
# Two servers, with equal weights:
servers = [1, 1]

# Four tasks:
task durations       = [3, 2, 1, 1]
desired start times  =  0  1  2  3
implied finish times =  3  3  3  4

# What happens:
- At time=3, both previously-busy servers will be free.
- We should start the last two tasks immediately.
- But your code waits until time=4 to start the last one.

# Expected result vs actual:
expected = [0, 1, 0, 1]
actual   = [0, 1, 0, 0]
```

**Problem 2: time ... increases ... too ... slowly**. The current code
increments time by 1 second per loop iteration. That makes sense during the
first `N` seconds (where `N` is number of tasks). But deeper into the future,
that slow pace can be a problem. If LeetCode were to feed your program tasks
with very large task durations, the loop would be needlessly chugging away for
a long time. For example, imagine the same servers as the example above, with
the following tasks: `[999999999, 999999999, 1, 1]`. A human could quickly
calculate the right answer, but your code could not. Granted, LeetCode limits
task durations to `200000` (not a very big number, so you could plow your way
through it pretty fast), but in my experience posting answers to the site for
this question, my solutions would fail for being too slow whenever I incremented time naively. The key is to check only the relevant times,
in the right order, of course ... which sounds like a good use case
for another heap.

Comment: "I experimented with this question but did not post anything because I assumed it was off-topic" It is, we're sorry for the confusion. Feel free to find us [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) if anything is unclear.